# Rx Kotlin retryWhen issue

Tags: android, kotlin, observable, rx-java

I am trying to use `.retryWhen()` operation to retry an api call in case of failure for 3 times every 5 seconds. Could someone please help me with this case as I cannot figure it out for the past few hours.

```
.retryWhen { errors ->
                errors
                    .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), { _: Throwable, i: Int -> i })
                    .flatMap { retryCount: Int ->
                        Observable.timer(
                            5.0.pow(retryCount.toDouble()).toLong(),
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS
                        )
                    }
            }
```

I am getting

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: ((Observer<in Int!>) -> Unit)!, p1: ((Throwable, Int) -> ???)!): Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: ObservableSource<out Int!>!, p1: BiFunction<in Throwable!, in Int!, out (???..???)>!): Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: (Mutable)Iterable<(???..???)>!, p1: BiFunction<in Throwable!, in (???..???), out (???..???)>!): Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
@CheckReturnValue @SchedulerSupport public final fun <U : Any!, R : Any!> zipWith(p0: (Mutable)Iterable<Int!>!, p1: ((Throwable, Int) -> ???)!): Observable<(???..???)>! defined in io.reactivex.Observable
```

I am also pasting the whole code I tried to execute:

```
private fun getOrderDetails(uuid: String) {
        apiClient.getOrderDetailsUsingUUID(uuid)
            .retryWhen { errors ->
                errors
                    .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), { _: Throwable, i: Int -> i })
                    .flatMap { retryCount: Int ->
                        Observable.timer(
                            5.0.pow(retryCount.toDouble()).toLong(),
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS
                        )
                    }
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ webOrderRequest ->
                _currentOrder.value = OrderState.OrderDetails(webOrderRequest.order!!)
                orderStatus(uuid, webOrderRequest.order)
            },
                { error ->
                    _currentOrder.value = OrderState.Error(getErrorMessage(error))
                    Log.e(TAG, getErrorMessage(error))
                }
            )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I case someone is looking for something similar. I came up with a solution which works fine for me.

```
.retryWhen { errors ->
                errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), BiFunction { throwable: Throwable, count: Int -> Pair(throwable, count) })
                    .flatMap { count: Pair<Throwable, Int> ->
                        if (count.second < 3) {
                            Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        } else {
                           Observable.error(count.first)
                        }
                    }
            }
```

**Extension for it:**.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

fun <T> Observable<T>.retryWhenError(retryCount: Int, delayInSeconds: Long): Observable<T> {
    return retryWhen { errors ->
        errors.zipWith(
            Observable.range(1, retryCount), BiFunction { throwable: Throwable, count: Int -> Pair(throwable, count) })
            .flatMap { count: Pair<Throwable, Int> ->
                if (count.second < retryCount) {
                    Observable.timer(delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                } else {
                    Observable.error(count.first)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I customize your extension to only retry after specific statuses, like 408, or 500**?

Comment: just check throwable exception instead of count.second < retryCount